# Passing an array of check-boxes with ajax using angular js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I need to do an ajax GET request, submitting an array of check-boxes (all with the same name):
eg:

> type[] = new
>
> type[] = used
>
> type[] = refurbished

This is required for an API I am trying to access.  However I am not sure how to achieve this.

I have everything else working with the API except for these check-boxes.

This is how the checkboxes are defined:

```
 self.types = ['new', 'used', 'refurbished'];
 //....
           <label ng-repeat="type in search.types">
                <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="type[]"
                        value="{{type}}"
                        > {{type}}
            </label>
```

And this is how I am adding values to be sent to the API, eg:

```
 dataObj['price'] = $scope.formData.max_price;
//need to do similar as this for the type[] checkboxes
```

And then they get sent to the API:

```
  return $http({
                url: APIUrl + "search/",
                method: "GET",
                params: dataObj
  });
  //etc
```

So the params that get posted to the API need to look like:

```
 price = 400000
 type[] = new
 type[] = refurbished
 //NB: "used" wasn't submitted as the "used" checkbox wasn't checked
```

^ this is NOT flexible, it is required by an API.

Many thanks

Comment: plnkr please. and also why are you not using ng-model on the checkbox?

Comment: Are you sure that the API requires `type[]=new` and `type[]=refurbished` etc? Most of the API's expect `type=new` and `type=refurbished` etc and then they convert that into an array. Can you point us to the API?

Comment: yes I am sure that is required by the API. Can't point you to it unfortunately as it is private. it is via GET method, so query string.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-model="checkbox1", ng-model="checkbox2", ng-model="checkbox3" and collect them into object.

data = {
price: price,
type1: checkbox1,
type2: checkbox2,
type3: checkbox3
}

Comment: Thanks...But they need to be submitted as "type[]=new,type=[]=used...etc" via ajax, not "type1=...type2=..."

Comment: Then is something wrong with your back-end implementation.
Or you than should add array of types to your object.

Comment: It is a query string GET request to an API we are using.

Comment: So as i say, push all types models to one array and send it or split it before sending. You can construct query out of strings.